# How to troubleshoot communication with a kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, jaeger

Setting up jaeger tracing...So previously I had a binary executable (jaeger-agent) running on a Linux CentOS 8 box alongside a server side application. The tracing spans were being sent to the jaeger-collector service (setup by kubernetes) on port 14250 and everything was working. Then recently we had to reboot the jaeger tracing service due to a system crash.  Now things have stopped working and from the logs there's a "504 Gateway Timeout" and the agent can no longer communicate with the collector.

In AWS, we were running a kubernetes service "jaeger-collector" that conformed to the service here
https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/blob/master/jaeger-production-template.yml with the only difference is that I'm using version 1.16.

There's no external IP with the service.  How do I use `curl` to test the communication with the jaeger-collector service? Or do I need an external IP and perhaps that's the reason for the Gateway Timeout? I tried using `curl` with the ClusterIP and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Wait so is your "binary executable jager-agent" outside of your Kubernetes cluster?  Or is it running in a pod in the cluster?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is, although I am very new to kubernetes and did not set up this configuration. But it was working before...and it's unclear to me what if anything changed. So I'm working on how to figure that out.

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying your file on a Kubernetes 1.16 cluster, and there are a couple of issues with it:

1. It uses apiVersions that were [decommed in Kubernetes 1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/). ie- `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` should become `apps/v1`.
2. The Deployments don't have any selectors and neither does the Daemonset.

> The .spec.selector field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage.

It seems like you are applying something that is super old.  Kubernetes notes the below in its doc, and so I wonder if this used to work on older versions of Kubernetes where selectors were defaulted.

> As of Kubernetes 1.8, you must specify a pod selector that matches the labels of the .spec.template. The pod selector will no longer be defaulted when left empty.

It seems like you should take a new approach-- in looking around, I found a couple of good tutorials [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-distributed-tracing-with-jaeger-on-kubernetes) and [here](https://thenewstack.io/best-practices-for-deploying-jaeger-on-kubernetes-in-production/), and Jaeger themselves offer a similar approach [here](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.19/operator/).  They all make use of [Kubernetes Operators](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/what-is-a-kubernetes-operator#:%7E:text=A%20Kubernetes%20operator%20is%20a,and%20managing%20a%20Kubernetes%20application.&text=A%20Kubernetes%20operator%20is%20an,behalf%20of%20a%20Kubernetes%20user.).

> A Kubernetes operator is an application-specific controller that extends the functionality of the Kubernetes API to create, configure, and manage instances of complex applications on behalf of a Kubernetes user

I don't know what you mean by *"So previously I had a binary executable (jaeger-agent) running on a Linux CentOS 8 box alongside a server side application"*

The file you are applying looks like it [deploys the agent as a daemonset](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/blob/master/jaeger-production-template.yml#L182-L185), which means the agent is run as a pod on each node of your cluster.  If it is running in your k8's cluster, then [this is how I normally approach troubleshooting kubernetes services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942591/service-cannot-communicate-with-rabbitmq-in-k8s-cluster/63943106#63943106).  If it is running outside of your cluster entirely, then you need to make sure the Service it talks to is exposed outside of the cluster probably using type LoadBalancer.